# R truncate a text file at an index

Tags: r, file

I have a text file `output.txt`. I would like to keep only the first `n` (for example, 1,000, known to me, surely no larger than the file size) characters and truncate the rest. If the file was small, I could do

```r
n <- 1000   # Just an example. I keep track of this. No worries.
f <- 'output.txt'
cat(readChar(f,pmin(n,file.info(f)$size)), file=f, append=FALSE)
cat("keep going", file=f, append=TRUE)
```

but the file can sometimes be very large and the above is inefficient. I am looking for something like the following C example:

```c
long n = 1000L;
FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");
fseek(fp, n, SEEK_SET);   /* this part */
fputs("keep going", fp);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since `readChar` will not read past an EOF marker, you do not need to use the `pmin` clause - this is already implicit in how `readChar` works. This means you can truncate your file (including the "keep going" addendum) with this one-liner:

```r
n <- 1000
f <- 'output.txt'

writeChar(paste(readChar(f, 1000), "Keep going", sep = "\n"), f)
```

Comment: Thanks. But can it be done without reading it by `readChar`? The file is sometimes huge, and I don't want to read the contents over and over again. I just want to move the "pointer" to `n` and then write from that position.

Comment: @chan1142 But you will not read the whole huge file, just the first `n` characters.

Comment: Or is `n` sometimes very large too?

Comment: Yes. `n` is very large too.

Comment: Are you just looking to overwrite some of the text at position `n`? My reading of your C code is that you are not actually truncating / shrinking the file but just overwriting a few characters at position `n`. Is that correct?

Comment: You are right. I am trying to overwrite from `n`. I see my question was a bit confusing. Sorry.